# Proper non-returning control function

Tags: c++

I have a function which shows some message, properly finishes the program and finally calls `exit(-1);`. Here is an example of usage:

```
Data SomeFunction()
{
  Data data;
  if (some_condition) {
    // filling the data
    return data;
  }
  ShowErrorAndExit("Some message");
  //return data - I don't want it here!
}
```

The problem is, the compiler says:

> warning: control reaches end of non-void function

However, this is not true, because the end of this function will never be reached. I don't want to add an unneeded return at the end of function; what else can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ShowErrorAndExit` should be labeled `[[noreturn]]`. This will remove the warning.

Example:

```
[[noreturn]] void ShowErrorAndExit(std::string message) {...}
```

Comment: +1. Note that this only works with C++11 and newer. If you are on an older version of C++ and using GCC (according to the error message, this seems to be the case), you may want to use [`__attribute__((noreturn))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html).

Comment: Compiler now says `warning: ‘noreturn’ function does return` on that function but my code isn't return anything

Comment: @ValeriyChistyakov I can't help without seeing how that function is implemented.

Comment: @ValeriyChistyakov What if you use `std::exit` instead of `exit`? Does the "noreturn function does return" go away?

Comment: `std::exit` didn't gelp. The problem (for some reason) was with another function, which I called from `ShowErrorAndExit`. When I moved that code inside this function, the warning went away

Answer (score 2):

Invert the logic:

```
Data SomeFunction() {
if (!some_condition)
    ShowErrorAndExit("Some message");
Data data;
// filling in the data
return data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can (and *should*) declare your `ShowErrorAndExit` function with the `[[noreturn]]` attribute ([link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/noreturn)). This will allow the compiler (if it's reasonably sane) to understand that your function never reaches the control point for which it issues the warning.

Something like this:

```cpp
[[ noreturn ]] void ShowErrorAndExit(const char* message);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may trick the compiler to think the `return` is always reached:

```
Data SomeFunction()
{
  Data data;
  if (! some_condition)
      ShowErrorAndExit("Some message");

  // fill the data

  return data;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can ignore the warning or, if your compiler provides a way to do so, disable it. Another option is to put a `throw` at the end of the function with a comment indicating that it's never supposed to execute.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `std::optional`, it lets you return your type `Data` or nothing at all a.k.a.`std::nullopt`.
Look here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional

Comment: The OP would still need a `return {};` at the end of the function.

Comment: @NathanOliver I don't think TS just opposes word `return`, he wants to evade returning default constructed type `Data`

Comment: The very last sentence in the Q is *I don't want to add unneeded return at the end of function, what else can I do?*

Comment: @NathanOliver Don't you thing that's odd and not practical? Well I guess you maybe right, it's just unusual. If so you can just reorder as you suggested.